# Adding button functionality individually in angularjs template

Tags: angularjs

I have a template. In the template, there are three boxes. Each box has **add** button, which will add an input field in that box. I have tried the following codes.

HTML

```
<div class="row">
        <div ng-repeat="item in items2">
          <div class="theBox">
            <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="addItem()">add</button>
            <h6>{{item.key}}</h6>

            <input ng-model="item.value">
          </div>
        </div>

</div>
```

AngularJs

```
 $scope.items2 = [
      {
        "key" : "a",
        "value" : []
      },
      {
        "key" : "b",
        "value" : []
      },
      {
        "key" : "c",
        "value" : []
      }
  ];


  $scope.addItem = function(){
    console.log("clicked ")
   angular.forEach($scope.items2, function(mm){
     mm.value.push({})
   })

  }
```

The Problem: If I click on add, it's creating an object inside each value, maybe because I have used the forEach-loop for each value. How can I add it individually?

Also The input tag is not added as well, how can I fix that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question it's not exactly clear.

If you are going to

> add an input field in that box

every time you click on the *add* button, then you will need another ng-repeat in your HTML.
Something like:

```
<div class="row">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items2">
      <div class="theBox">
        <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="addItem(item)">add</button>
        <h6>{{item.key}}</h6>

        <input ng-repeat="itemValue in item.value" ng-model="itemValue.text">
      </div>
    </div>
```

and your javascript to:

```
$scope.addItem = function(item){ 
    item.value.push({text:""});
}
```

Comment: This is really close what i am expecting. however the controller is not taking the values from the input field once its created

Comment: Yeah, my bad. as @Maxim Shoustin suggested in his post, you need to create a "text" parameter for your input. i'll edit my post accordingly

Answer (score 2):

> which will add an input field in that box.

If I understand you right you want to add `<input>`*s* to specific box.

I would write something that:

```
<div class="row">
        <div ng-repeat="item in items2">
          <div class="theBox">
            <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="addItem(item)">add</button>
            <h6>{{item.key}}</h6>
          <div ng-repeat="value in item.values">
             <input  ng-model="value.text">
            </div>    
          </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

and method will be:

```
 $scope.addItem = function(selectedItem){
   selectedItem.values.push({text:""});  
 }
```

<kbd>[Demo Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GmiPLQOVEaKaie5qBi29?p=preview)</kbd>

---

#### Tips:

- If you have list og inputs, the good practice to name it `values` and
  not `value` in `{
         "key" : "a",
         "value" : []
       },`
- `input` `ng-model` is based on string and not object so will be better to set `{text:""}`  and `<input  ng-model="value.text">`